# Handle uploaded SQLite file in Symfony2

Tags: sqlite, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm new on Symfony. How can I handle with uploaded SQLite files (I need update my big MySQL database from these small bases)? I can't save their parameters to parameters.yml because these files are dynamic.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to update my global mysql base from data on small sqlite db. I receive these sqlite databases from my clients (i have simple upload service for that).

Comment: So you have a main database connection configured in your application config which controls the connection to your MySQL database? And when the SqlLite file is uploaded you want to load a set of entities from that database file into your main database and after that has succeeded just remove that file and forget about it?

Comment: Exactly! I'm looking for a solution for this since many days. Thank you for any help.